# Missing operator in query expression with OleDb going into an Access database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am getting an error:

Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression.

Here is the SQL that is objected to:

[image]

I am guessing that Access feels it needs more parentheses somewhere. I have tried adding them in different places, with no luck so far.

Comment: You have three `WHERE` statements...  Can you please post this as text and not a picture...?

Comment: change the 2nd `WHERE` to `AND`

Comment: could you print the value of ssql?  You should also be able to paste that value into the SQL view of a new query, that could help you debug.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ( at the after the from

```
      .....FROM ";
    sSQL += "[ComponentText] .....
```

instead of

```
    sSQL += "([ComponentText] ...
```

Answer (score 0):

well, I am not sure what exactly was wrong, but I did revise the SQL and got it to work. The revision involved using a SELECT FROM (SELECT   ) AS Q  ... WHERE Component.Text IN (SELECT   ).

here is the sSQL that worked:

SELECT Q.[ComponentCounter] FROM (SELECT [ComponentText].[ComponentCounter],[ComponentText].[TextId],[ComponentText].[Text] FROM [ComponentText] WHERE [ComponentText].[TextId] = @bomgroupid AND [ComponentText].[Text] = @bomdevice) AS Q  INNER JOIN [Connection] as P ON Q.[ComponentCounter]=P.[CompCounter] WHERE  Q.[ComponentCounter] IN (SELECT [ComponentText].[ComponentCounter] FROM [ComponentText] WHERE [ComponentText].[TextId] = 160040 AND [ComponentText].[Text]= @type );

I am not in the habit of using Aliases, but it really helped simplify this SQL statement, both for myself and MS Access. I will have to remember that. Thanks everyone for the help.